# comparing RGBA from Kinect by pixel

Tags: c++, kinect, rgb

I'm trying to get a Kinect to find a red shape and seem to be having difficulty comparing the actual RGBA values from each pixel. The code should be pretty self-explanatory. The text output file is just for me to get a quick representation of what's getting assigned to the array for future calculations.

```
void CColorBasics::getRGB (BYTE* bitPointer, LONG width, LONG height)
{
int red, green, blue, alpha;

int arr[640][480];
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("asdf.txt");

for (int i=0; i<height; i ++)
{
    for (int ii=0; ii<width; ii = ii = ii+4)
    {
            blue = (int)bitPointer[ii];
            green = (int)bitPointer[ii+1];
            red = (int)bitPointer[ii+2];
            alpha = (int)bitPointer[ii+3];

        //calculate differences between BG and R and store result in an array
        if (red > (green+blue) && red >= 150)
        {
            arr[i][ii] = 1;
            myfile << "1";
        }
        else
        {
            arr[i][ii] = 0;
            myfile << "0";
        }
    }
    myfile << "\n";
}

    myfile.close();
}
```

Instead of getting a pattern that resembles anything close to what the RGBA sees, I get some semi-random stuff that seems to have to do with how much red is in the picture, but certainly isn't formatted correctly. Essentially, if a pixel is "significantly red", I would like a '1' to be stored in that pixel's location in the array[][] - otherwise, store a '0' in that spot. Tips would definitely be appreciated!

Comment: `ii = ii = ii+4` in your for..loop *probably* has no side effects ... but I'd avoid it nevertheless. Even though thinking about it *tells* me it ought to work. Also, next time use `x` and `y` as loop counters. But I don't see obvious errors in your code. Are your width and height equal to or less than your array size? Does your debug show sensible values of you write out R values, without the "redness" check?

Comment: You might have better luck checking the color in a hue/saturation based color space. A simple first try might be to convert to [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and any pixel with a hue angle between +/- 30 degrees would be considered "red". (You might narrow that down depending on your particular situation.)